# git show on a sepecific file return 'fatal: bad object'

Tags: git, show

I am using **git show** to retrieve a file content on a specific revision of [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) which is hosted in Github. This is my git command which I run at root of the project:

```
git show 63cbc8439357f496ce630c2eb35b2cf02342fa4b~1:rest-spec
```

However, I received following error:

```
fatal: bad object 63cbc8439357f496ce630c2eb35b2cf02342fa4b~1:rest-spec
```

The **rest-spec** is existed in the version **63cbc8439357f496ce630c2eb35b2cf02342fa4b~1** since, it is changed in the next revision. You can see the change of the next revision [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/63cbc8439357f496ce630c2eb35b2cf02342fa4b) in Github and I verified it with my local clone with the following command:

```
git show 63cbc8439357f496ce630c2eb35b2cf02342fa4b
```

This is output of above git show (I just include **the change of rest-spec**):

```
diff --git a/rest-spec b/rest-spec
deleted file mode 160000
index b3ab724..0000000
--- a/rest-spec
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-Subproject commit b3ab72486fae1b5c5a5397356a3e113bf72eb6d5
```

Highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `rest-spec` is a submodule of the [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) repository and, thus, is not an object belonging to (directly stored in) that repository. Look at the [tree of the **63cbc8439357f496ce630c2eb35b2cf02342fa4b~1** revision](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/51bec4ec6c1818a8d63b46cc33797b9ba122212b) to make sure that `rest-spec` is different from other objects. It is recorded in the `elasticsearch` repository through the [`.gitmodules`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/51bec4ec6c1818a8d63b46cc33797b9ba122212b/.gitmodules) file, and the contents of the referenced repository [elasticsearch-rest-api-spec](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rest-api-spec.git) are made available as a subdirectory in the working tree of the superproject (i.e. the `elasticsearch` repository) via the `git submodule` commands. For more details see the [Submodules chapter in the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and the [documentation of the `git submodule` command](https://git-scm.com/ref/git-submodule).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I used `diff --ignore-submodules` to filter the submodule and it did not appear in the result. How can we find out a file is submodule? How we can see the content of a submodule file?

Comment: I encountered another error. I would appreciate if you could possibly help me to solve it @Leon . In the commit  **e7e1667a26de5472e3419c586682b92c37c6e7d3**, `diff --ignore-submodules` dose not filter the sub-module and **rest-spec** is appearing in `git diff`. Do you know how can I **filter sub-module** in `git diff`? 
Thanks

Comment: @MohsenLaali My source of information is the official documentation. It suggests that `git diff --ignore-submodules=all` should ignore all changes in submodules, but it also states that `git diff --ignore-submodules` (without any explicitly specified mode) defaults to `--ignore-submodules=all`. However the case with the commit **e7e1667a26de5472e3419c586682b92c37c6e7d3** is that **rest-spec** in that commit is not a submodule but an actual object of the repository (of type symlink). That's why it appears in the diff.

Comment: Thank you @Leon for your response. I am wondering if there is any way that I can find out a change is happen in symlink or submodule etc from out put of `git diff `. For example, I saw `-Subproject commit 2f5f78f24d8fbacf69c83ab7545654c83965e846` in `git diff` of the commit **e7e1667a26de5472e3419c586682b92c37c6e7d3** before **rest-spec**, is it indication of **symlink** for **rest-spec** ? I have filter the **symlink** from `git diff` with `--diff-filter=t`. I just wondering is it the right approach to exclude **symlink** from `git diff` results.

Comment: Sorry for many follow up questions @Leon , [the git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/) is not clear enough for  me to understand how git is working. Do you know good place to learn about the git (specially for **git diff**, **submodule** and **symlink**)? 
Thank you again.

Comment: @MohsenLaali Unfortunately I cannot advise a better and more reliable source of information than the official documentation (unless you are willing to read the source code). When you hit the limits of documentation, try playing with git commands and options on a small test repository until you figure out how they work.

Comment: Thank you @Leon for your advice.